# Import information from a website to a cell

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I want to import information from a website to an Excel spreadsheet.

```vb
Dim request As Object
Dim response As String
Dim html As New HTMLDocument
Dim website As String
Dim price As Variant

website = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/EURUSD=X?p=EURUSD=X"

Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

request.Open "GET", website, False

request.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"

request.send

response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)

html.body.innerHTML = response

price = html.getElementsByClassName("Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)").Item(0).innerText
```

How do I put information into an Excel cell?

Comment: Try using `Html.getElementById("quote-market-notice").ParentNode.FirstChild.innerText` instead of your current attempt in order for it to be less fragile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your code to define the worksheet and create a variable for the worksheet:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

and then you use it when you print it to your cell.

```
ws.Cells(1, "A").Value = price 'Print price to cell A1
```

---

I use this code to retrieve Exchange rate prices, something to elaborate with:

```
'Download Exchange Rates
Dim HTMLE As New HTMLDocument, elemE As Object, URLE$
Dim oElementE As Object
Dim GetPriceExchange As String
    
URLE$ = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/USDSEK=x/" 'ExchangeRate. Only one combination is retrieved. The other is calculated

With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", URLE, False
    .send
    HTMLE.body.innerHTML = .responseText

    Set elemE = HTMLE.getElementById("quote-market-notice").PreviousSibling.PreviousSibling 'If error still persist, try to close END with before this line of code.. https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/3q9pzy/i_receive_error_91_object_variable_or_with_block/
    'Debug.Print elemE.innerText
    GetPriceExchange = elemE.innerText 'test if any price is retrieved from yahoo finance
    'GetPriceExchange = Replace(GetPriceExchange, ".", ",")'change decimal standard
End With
```